# How is Googlebot finding a 404 from a referring page that also doesn't exist?

Tags: google-search-console, 404

I had a problem with a Japanese keyword hack a while ago and am still having 404 issues in GSC. I 410'd all pages that don't exist but am still having problems. Whenever I inspect a page that Googlebot found as a "Not Found (404)" I notice that is also shows a Referring page. However, that page doesn't exist either.

How is Googlebot finding these Referring pages that don't even exist?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did the pages ever exist? and, consider (even if these pages were never valid), were they delivering content because of how the server was configured?

```
# this .htaccess delivers content for non-exitant pages
# if the index.php does not notify with a 404 for non-exitant pages
# then these pages exist.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# Note: Wordpress does provide a 404 when it can not deliver the page.
```

If they did then google is using its cached copy from when it did exist. If it actually never existed then google has made an error. Perhaps there was a broken DNS entry at some point in the past?

There should be a button that says something like, "fixed," which would remove the message from the search console. But, it is harmless; The 404 notices are just to be helpful so webmasters can fix them for their visitors.

---

Note Google is doing a lot of updating which may relate to why these surfaced now.